# Fazer um filtro no datagridview (row filter)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tenho um banco de dados SQL com duas tabelas. Uma delas armazena medidas criadas(**tabela 1**) e a outra ações destas medidas(**tabela 2**).

Inseri no formulário um `datagridView` com os dados da *tabela 1* e criei uma coluna com o nome "`SITUACAO`" que indica o status da última ação criada para aquela medida. Por exemplo "*atrasada*", "*concluida*" ou "*no prazo*". Este status está referenciado a *tabela 2*.

A coluna "`SITUACAO`" preenchi com um `FOR` que passa toda *tabela 2* e verifica a situação da ação daquela medida.

```
dtg.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "no prazo";
```

O datagridView foi populado corretamente com os dados e a coluna "SITUACAO".

Gostaria de fazer um filtro utilizando a coluna "SITUACAO"

```
`((DataTable)dtg.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("SITUACAO = 'no prazo'");`
```

Utilizando o `row filter` apresenta um erro indicando que a coluna não existe. Sei que a coluna "*SITUACAO*" não está no `data source`.

- Existe alguma outra maneira de se fazer este filtro?

Código

```
private void frmDossie_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListarDossie();            
    }
private void ListarDossie()
    {
        try
        {
            novoDossie = new RegraNegocio.DossieRegraNegocio();
            dtgDossie.DataSource = novoDossie.ListarDossie();
            Status();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
private void Status()
    {
        int linhas = dtgDossie.Rows.Count;
        double dataSituacao;
        DateTime dataFinal, dataInicial;

        DataTable dadosTabela = new DataTable();
        novoDossie = new RegraNegocio.DossieRegraNegocio();
        dadosTabela = novoDossie.ListarAcoes();

        int linhas2 = dadosTabela.Rows.Count;

        if (linhas > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < linhas2; j++)
                {
                    dataInicial = Convert.ToDateTime(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_INICIAL"]);
                    Convert.ToInt32(dataSituacao = DateTime.Today.Subtract(dataInicial).TotalDays);

                    string tabela = dadosTabela.Rows[j]["ID_DOSSIE"].ToString();
                    string dtg = dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["ID_DOSSIE"].Value.ToString();

                    switch (Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["ID_TIPO_ACAO"]))
                    {
                        case 6: //Obra Concluida                                    
                            if (tabela == dtg && string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString())==false)
                            {
                                dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "OBRA CONCLUÍDA";
                            break;
                        case 5: //Envio CCO
                            if (tabela == dtg)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["COMPROMISSO_OBRA"].Value).AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["REPACTUACAO"].Value)) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(+15))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Prazo Obra Vencendo";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) == false)
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "CCO Concluida";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao < Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "CCO no Prazo";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao > Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "CCO atrasada";

                                } 
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4: //Construcao
                            if (tabela == dtg)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["COMPROMISSO_OBRA"].Value).AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["REPACTUACAO"].Value)) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(+15))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Prazo Obra Vencendo";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) == false)
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Construção Concluida";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao < Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Construção no Prazo";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao > Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Construção atrasada";

                                } 
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3: //Liberacao Obra
                            if (tabela == dtg)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["COMPROMISSO_OBRA"].Value).AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["REPACTUACAO"].Value)) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(+15))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Prazo Obra Vencendo";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) == false)
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Liberação Concluida";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao < Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Liberação no Prazo";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao > Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Liberação atrasada";

                                } 
                            }
                            break;
                            case 2: //Envio AF
                            if (tabela == dtg)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["COMPROMISSO_OBRA"].Value).AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["REPACTUACAO"].Value)) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(+15))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Prazo Obra Vencendo";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) == false)
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "AF Concluida";

                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao < Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Assinatura AF no Prazo";
                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao > Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Assinatura AF atrasada";
                                } 
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1: //Analise
                            if (tabela == dtg)
                                {
                                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["COMPROMISSO_OBRA"].Value).AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["REPACTUACAO"].Value)) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(+15))                                       
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Prazo Obra Vencendo";

                                }                                   
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) == false)
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Análise Concluida";
                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao < Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Análise no Prazo";
                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["DATA_FINAL"].ToString()) && dataSituacao > Convert.ToInt32(dadosTabela.Rows[j]["PRAZO"]))
                                {
                                    dtgDossie.Rows[i].Cells["SITUACAO"].Value = "Análise atrasada";
                                } 
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
private void btnPesquisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((DataTable)dtgDossie.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("SITUACAO = 'Análise no Prazo'");
    }
```

Código da camada Regra Negócio

```
public DataTable ListarDossie()
    {
        try
        {
            novoDossie = new AcessoDados.DossieAcessoDados();
            DataTable dadosTabela = new DataTable();
            dadosTabela = novoDossie.ListarDossie();
            return dadosTabela;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
public DataTable ListarAcoes()
    {
        try
        {
            novoDossie = new AcessoDados.DossieAcessoDados();
            DataTable dadosTabela = new DataTable();
            dadosTabela = novoDossie.ListarAcoes();
            return dadosTabela;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Código da camada acesso dados

```
 public DataTable ListarDossie()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(Conexao.stringConexao))
            {
                conexao.Open();

                sql.Append("SELECT PROJETO.NUMERO_PROJETO, CLIENTES.NOME_CLIENTE, DOSSIE.*, TIPO_DOSSIE.TIPO_DOSSIE FROM DOSSIE");
                sql.Append(" INNER JOIN PROJETO ON PROJETO.ID_PROJETO = DOSSIE.ID_PROJETO");
                sql.Append(" INNER JOIN DADOS_OBRA ON PROJETO.ID_PROJETO = DADOS_OBRA.ID_PROJETO");
                sql.Append(" INNER JOIN CLIENTES ON DADOS_OBRA.ID_CLIENTE = CLIENTES.ID_CLIENTE");
                sql.Append(" INNER JOIN TIPO_DOSSIE ON TIPO_DOSSIE.ID_TIPO_DOSSIE = DOSSIE.ID_TIPO_DOSSIE");

                comandoSql.CommandText = sql.ToString();
                comandoSql.Connection = conexao;
                dadosTabela.Load(comandoSql.ExecuteReader());
                return dadosTabela;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro no método ListarDossie. Caso o problema persista, entre em contato com o Administrador do sistema.");
        }
    }
 public DataTable ListarAcoes()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(Conexao.stringConexao))
            {
                conexao.Open();

                sql.Append("SELECT * FROM ACAO_DOSSIE");

                comandoSql.CommandText = sql.ToString();
                comandoSql.Connection = conexao;
                dadosTabela.Load(comandoSql.ExecuteReader());
                return dadosTabela;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro no método ListarAcoes. Caso o problema persista, entre em contato com o Administrador do sistema.");
        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Existe, poste o seu código o nome e estrutura das tabelas

Comment: Adicionei uma parte do código para ajudar na solução do meu problema. Veja se atende ou necessita de mais alguma parte. @LeandroAngelo